# Manually Link React Native Library (FB SDK) for iOS on Linux

Tags: ios, react-native

Is it possible to manually link a library in a react native app when developing on a Linux (Ubuntu) device without manually building the app (I am using the Expo client to test and debug).  Because I am on a Linux device, I do not have XCode, and all of the instructions I have found only show how to link libraries using XCode, and they all seem to assume that I have built the app already, or give instructions for building the app (which don't apply to me).

The reason I am asking is I am trying to test the FB login button in my app, but after installing and linking the `react-native-fbsdk` library, opening the login page in my app results in an error: `Invariant Violation: Native component for "RCTFBLoginButton" does not exist"`.  The closest/simplest answer I have found so far seems like it should be the answer in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/8f2txr/fb_sdk_invariant_violation_native_component_for/) question, but again it requires XCode, and I'm not sure how to emulate those commands in the command line (or whatever way they can be done).

Comment: That's because react-native-fbsdk requires linking of native components and libraries, only possible for iOS **if you have Xcode**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using expo, you should use their [facebook implementation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook).

I had a lot of trouble using the login with fbsdk, and the expo sdk is doing the job quite easier.